# Set Cloudant AuthSession cookie from my domain?

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

Apple's Safari browser does not accept third party cookies by default.  I do not want to require that my users change their privacy settings.

Is it possible to set the AuthSession cookie for Cloudant from my domain or to avoid this problem some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this problem by setting up a Virtual Host in Cloudant.

Specifically, I added a 'data.mydomain.net' virtual host in my Cloudant account and mapped a CNAME record to 'username.cloudant.com' with my domain name provider.

This is covered in Cloudant's Developer FAQs here:

https://cloudant.com/for-developers/faq/development/